# Populating another sheet using keywords

Tags: vba, button, keyword, excel-2016

I have a set of keywords (a, b, c, d) to be used from a master sheet and populate them respectively to other sheets by these keywords. For example, if my master sheet locates the keyword "a" then i want the row with details having keyword "a" to move to the sheet named as "a". Similarly if it finds the keyword "b" then the entire row needs to be moved to sheet "b". I want to use a "button" which i have named it as "update". when someone clicks on this button i want the master sheet to perform the search action so that it seperates the details by its keywords into different sheets. I want to do this using VBA. Can someone help ??

**

```
Sub UpdateMeetings()
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, erow As Long
lastrow = Sheets("Visit Details").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
For i = 2 To lastrow
If Sheets("Visit Details").Cells(i, 6) = "apple" Then
Sheets("Visit Details").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("apple").Select
lastrow = Sheets("apple").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
erow = lastrow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End If
Sheets("Visit Details").Select
Next i
End Sub
```

**

I used this code and it works perfect only if the general comments has only one word "apple" mentioned in the column
. But i wanted to pick the keyword "apple" from the column general comments where it says " Rita had a call with Tom in regards to buying apple from a store nearby"... but when there is a long sentence it doesnt work.. can someone help in how to tell excel to pick sentences that has word "apple" in it and move the entire row to sheet "apple"

Comment: Sub UpdateMeetings()
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, erow As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Visit Details").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
If Sheets("Visit Details").Cells(i, 6) = "apple" Then
Sheets("Visit Details").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 17)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("apple").Select
lastRow = Sheets("apple").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

erow = lastRow + 1
ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveWorkbook.Save

End If
Sheets("Visit Details").Select
Next i

End Sub

Comment: I used this code but it does not work... So i wanted to pick the keyword "apple" from the column general comments where is says " Rita had a call with Tom in regards to buying apple from a store nearby"... but i dont know why it does not work... looks like i have written it wrong.. can someone help in how to tell excel to pick sentences that has word "apple" in it and move the entire row to sheet "apple"